# Using CSV premier league match data to update an object value java and return to CSV

Tags: java, csv, oop

I am new to Java and I am attempting to manipulate some football match data in order to get a more in-depth understanding of the results. I have managed to get it to read from the CSV and I can get the individual values. The CSV format is like this fopr about 400 rows:

```
Arsenal,Leicester,4,3,H  
Brighton,Man City,0,2,A
Chelsea,Burnley,2,3,A
Crystal Palace,Huddersfield,0,3,A
Everton,Stoke,1,0,H
Southampton,Swansea,0,0,D
```

What I have struggled with is to retrieve the home team and away teams(objects and unsure how to match the string from the CSV to them): current points, league position goal, difference along with the match in a row in excel (I plan to use an artificial neural network to predict matches from this data) then I would like to match and update the correct object of each team e.g.if home team is Arsenal and they win 2-0 update Team Arsenal() to have 3 more points, 2 more goals scored, update league table position. Once this is done it will read the next result and repeat. 
I know this is a lot but I am really struggling on these parts so would really appreciate some help for a newbie to java.
Here is my current code:

**`InputHere.java`:**

```
package BasicP;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InputHere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Match> matches = new ArrayList<>();
        Path logFile = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Lewys\\Documents", "FinalofFootballDataws.csv");

        try (BufferedReader read
                = Files.newBufferedReader(logFile, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
            String firstLine = read.readLine();
            while (firstLine != null) {
                String[] variables = firstLine.split(","); 
                String homeName = variables[0];
                String awayName = variables[1];
                String strHomeScore = variables[2];
                String strAwayScore = variables[3];
                int homeScore = Integer.parseInt(strHomeScore);
                int awayScore = Integer.parseInt(strAwayScore);

                firstLine = read.readLine();
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return;
    }

}
```

**`Team.java`:**

```
public class Team {

    private String teamName;
    private int numberWin;
    private int numberDraw;
    private int numberLoss;
    private int matchesPlayed;
    private int points;
    private int goalsScored;
    private int goalsConceded;
    private int tablePosition;

    public Team(String teamName, int numberWin, int numberDraw,
                int numberLoss, int matchesPlayed, int points,
                int goalsScored, int goalsConceded, int tablePosition) {

    }

    public int getNumberWin() {
        return numberWin;
    }

    public int getNumberDraw() {
        return numberDraw;
    }

    public int getNumberLoss() {
        return numberLoss;
    }

    public int getMatchesPlayed() {
        return matchesPlayed;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public int getGoalsScored() {
        return goalsScored;
    }

    public int getGoalsConceded() {
        return goalsConceded;
    }

    public int getTablePosition() {
        return tablePosition;
    }

    public void setNumberWin(int i) {
        numberWin = numberWin + i;
    }

    public void setNumberDraw(int i) {
        numberDraw = numberDraw + i;
    }

    public void setNumberLoss(int i) {
        numberLoss = numberLoss + i;
    }

    public void setMatchesPlayed(int i) {
        matchesPlayed = matchesPlayed + i;
    }

    public void setPoints(int i) {
        points = points + i;
    }

    public void setGoalsScored(int i) {
        goalsScored = goalsScored + i;
    }

    public void setGoalsConceded(int i) {
        goalsConceded = goalsConceded + i;
    }

    public void settablePosition(int i) {
        tablePosition = i;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }
}
```

Comment: What headers would or do you have for the csv data? Like *Home Team*, *Away Team*, *Score home*, *Score away*, *Result* or similar?

Comment: The headers are HomeTeam, AwayTeam, HG, AG, R

Comment: @deHaar sorry forgot to tag

Comment: No problem, got the comment anyway... Well, in my opinion, you are in need of more objects if you want to decently maintain the Premier League Table by csv files per matchday. Your current approach holds the table position in the `Team`, but it is an attribute of the table, I think... You could make a class `PremierLeague` that holds all matches per matchday and adjusts the position of the `Team`s by setting only relevant entries, like goals, points, matches played and so on.

Comment: @daHaar that is a good idea and I shall look at implementing that! just wondering about how I match the first string (homeTeam) to the correct object home team ?

Comment: Give the `PremierLeague` a class attribute `List<Team>` or `Set<Team>` to have all teams of a season. Then you can find the team by its name there... To implement even a simple representation of a league with its teams, matchdays and matches is not trivial, but it is a very good progr amming practice. For anything extending a single season use a database...

Comment: If you have a `Team arsenal` and a `String teamNameFromCsvFile` from the csv file, then do something like `if (teamNameFromCsvFile.equals(arsenal.getTeamName()) { // add match data to team arsenal }` in order to match the team name. In a `List<Team> teams` you could do `teams.forEach(team -> { if team.getTeamName().equals(teamNameFromCsvFile) { ... }});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try solve your issue. 
Firt a write a CSVReader, but I suggest you to try using a specific library for it to better manage all csv format.

```
public class FootballMatchCSVReader {

    public List<FootballMatch> read(String filePath) throws IOException {
        return readAllLines(filePath).stream().map(line -> mapToFootballMatch(line.split(","))).collect(toList());
    }

    private List<String> readAllLines(String filePath) throws IOException {
        return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));
    }

    private FootballMatch mapToFootballMatch(String[] args) {
        return new FootballMatch(args[0],args[1],Integer.valueOf(args[2]),Integer.valueOf(args[3]),args[4].charAt(0));
    }
}
```

That return a List of FootballMatch

```
public class FootballMatch {

    private String homeTeam;
    private String awayTeam;
    private int homeTeamScore;
    private int awayTeamScore;
    private char finalResult;

    public FootballMatch(String homeTeam, String awayTeam, int homeTeamScore, int awayTeamScore, char winner) {
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
        this.homeTeamScore = homeTeamScore;
        this.awayTeamScore = awayTeamScore;
        this.finalResult = winner;
    }

    public String getHomeTeam() {
        return homeTeam;
    }

    public void setHomeTeam(String homeTeam) {
        this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
    }

    public String getAwayTeam() {
        return awayTeam;
    }

    public void setAwayTeam(String awayTeam) {
        this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
    }

    public int getHomeTeamScore() {
        return homeTeamScore;
    }

    public void setHomeTeamScore(int homeTeamScore) {
        this.homeTeamScore = homeTeamScore;
    }

    public int getAwayTeamScore() {
        return awayTeamScore;
    }

    public void setAwayTeamScore(int awayTeamScore) {
        this.awayTeamScore = awayTeamScore;
    }

    public char getFinalResult() {
        return finalResult;
    }

    public void setFinalResult(char finalResult) {
        this.finalResult = finalResult;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FootballMatch{" +
                "homeTeam='" + homeTeam + '\'' +
                ", awayTeam='" + awayTeam + '\'' +
                ", homeTeamScore=" + homeTeamScore +
                ", awayTeamScore=" + awayTeamScore +
                ", finalResult=" + finalResult +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Now I write a FootballMatchStatisticsEngine that compute the TeamStatistic for each match

```
public class TeamStatistic {

    private String teamName;
    private int numberWin;
    private int numberDraw;
    private int numberLoss;
    private int matchesPlayed;
    private int points;
    private int goalsScored;
    private int goalsConceded;
    private int tablePosition;

    public TeamStatistic(String teamName, int numberWin, int numberDraw, int numberLoss, int matchesPlayed, int points, int goalsScored, int goalsConceded, int tablePosition) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.numberWin = numberWin;
        this.numberDraw = numberDraw;
        this.numberLoss = numberLoss;
        this.matchesPlayed = matchesPlayed;
        this.points = points;
        this.goalsScored = goalsScored;
        this.goalsConceded = goalsConceded;
        this.tablePosition = tablePosition;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public int getNumberWin() {
        return numberWin;
    }

    public void setNumberWin(int numberWin) {
        this.numberWin = numberWin;
    }

    public int getNumberDraw() {
        return numberDraw;
    }

    public void setNumberDraw(int numberDraw) {
        this.numberDraw = numberDraw;
    }

    public int getNumberLoss() {
        return numberLoss;
    }

    public void setNumberLoss(int numberLoss) {
        this.numberLoss = numberLoss;
    }

    public int getMatchesPlayed() {
        return matchesPlayed;
    }

    public void setMatchesPlayed(int matchesPlayed) {
        this.matchesPlayed = matchesPlayed;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public int getGoalsScored() {
        return goalsScored;
    }

    public void setGoalsScored(int goalsScored) {
        this.goalsScored = goalsScored;
    }

    public int getGoalsConceded() {
        return goalsConceded;
    }

    public void setGoalsConceded(int goalsConceded) {
        this.goalsConceded = goalsConceded;
    }

    public int getTablePosition() {
        return tablePosition;
    }

    public void setTablePosition(int tablePosition) {
        this.tablePosition = tablePosition;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TeamStatistic{" +
                "teamName='" + teamName + '\'' +
                ", numberWin=" + numberWin +
                ", numberDraw=" + numberDraw +
                ", numberLoss=" + numberLoss +
                ", matchesPlayed=" + matchesPlayed +
                ", points=" + points +
                ", goalsScored=" + goalsScored +
                ", goalsConceded=" + goalsConceded +
                ", tablePosition=" + tablePosition +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
public class FootballMatchStatisticsEngine {

    public List<TeamStatistic> computeTeamStatistics(List<FootballMatch> footballMatches) {
        List<TeamStatistic> teamStatistics = getTeamStatistics(footballMatches);
        updatePosition(teamStatistics);
        return teamStatistics;
    }

    private void updatePosition(List<TeamStatistic> teamStatistics) {
        /*
        This function apply the relative table position to each TeamStatistics.
         */
               IntStream.range(0,teamStatistics.size()).forEach(i -> teamStatistics.get(i).setTablePosition(i+1));
    }

    private List<TeamStatistic> getTeamStatistics(List<FootballMatch> footballMatches) {
        /*
        The flat operation explode each match into two different TeamStatistics. One for home team and one for away team.
        After I compute the groupBy operation over team name and reduce the resulting list of Team statistics sumurizing her data.
         */
        return footballMatches
                .stream()
                .flatMap(fm -> footballMatchtoTeamStatistics(fm).stream())
                .collect(groupingBy(TeamStatistic::getTeamName, reducing(getTeamStatisticReduceOperation())))
                .values().stream().map(Optional::get)
                .sorted(comparingInt(TeamStatistic::getPoints).reversed())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private BinaryOperator<TeamStatistic> getTeamStatisticReduceOperation() {
        return (x, y) ->
                new TeamStatistic(
                        x.getTeamName(),
                        x.getNumberWin() + y.getNumberWin(),
                        x.getNumberDraw() + y.getNumberDraw(),
                        x.getNumberLoss() + y.getNumberLoss(),
                        x.getMatchesPlayed() + y.getMatchesPlayed(),
                        x.getPoints() + y.getPoints(),
                        x.getGoalsScored() + y.getGoalsScored(),
                        x.getGoalsConceded() + y.getGoalsConceded(), 0);
    }

    private List<TeamStatistic> footballMatchtoTeamStatistics(FootballMatch footballMatch) {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new TeamStatistic(
                        footballMatch.getHomeTeam(),
                        footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'H' ? 1 : 0,
                        footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'D' ? 1 : 0,
                        footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'A' ? 1 : 0,
                        1,
                        footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'H' ? 3 : footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'D' ? 1 : 0,
                        footballMatch.getHomeTeamScore(),
                        footballMatch.getAwayTeamScore(),
                        0),
                new TeamStatistic(
                        footballMatch.getAwayTeam(),
                        footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'A' ? 1 : 0,
                        footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'D' ? 1 : 0,
                        footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'H' ? 1 : 0,
                        1,
                        footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'A' ? 3 : footballMatch.getFinalResult() == 'D' ? 1 : 0,
                        footballMatch.getAwayTeamScore(),
                        footballMatch.getHomeTeamScore(),
                        0)
        );
    }

}
```

To test this code I write a file with the follow lines:

```
Arsenal,Leicester,4,3,H
Man City,Leicester,2,1,H
Brighton,Man City,0,2,A
Chelsea,Arsenal,0,2,A
Chelsea,Burnley,2,3,A
Crystal Palace,Huddersfield,0,3,A
Everton,Stoke,1,0,H
Southampton,Swansea,0,0,D
```

running the follow code

```
    FootballMatchCSVReader reader = new FootballMatchCSVReader();
        FootballMatchStatisticsEngine statisticsEngine = new FootballMatchStatisticsEngine();
        try {
            List<FootballMatch> footbalMatches = reader.read("src/test/resources/input.txt");
            List<TeamStatistic> teamStatistics = statisticsEngine.computeTeamStatistics(footbalMatches);
            teamStatistics.forEach(t -> System.out.println(t));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the output

```
TeamStatistic{teamName='Arsenal', numberWin=2, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=0, matchesPlayed=2, points=6, goalsScored=6, goalsConceded=3, tablePosition=1}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Man City', numberWin=2, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=0, matchesPlayed=2, points=6, goalsScored=4, goalsConceded=1, tablePosition=2}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Huddersfield', numberWin=1, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=0, matchesPlayed=1, points=3, goalsScored=3, goalsConceded=0, tablePosition=3}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Everton', numberWin=1, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=0, matchesPlayed=1, points=3, goalsScored=1, goalsConceded=0, tablePosition=4}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Burnley', numberWin=1, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=0, matchesPlayed=1, points=3, goalsScored=3, goalsConceded=2, tablePosition=5}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Southampton', numberWin=0, numberDraw=1, numberLoss=0, matchesPlayed=1, points=1, goalsScored=0, goalsConceded=0, tablePosition=6}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Swansea', numberWin=0, numberDraw=1, numberLoss=0, matchesPlayed=1, points=1, goalsScored=0, goalsConceded=0, tablePosition=7}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Stoke', numberWin=0, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=1, matchesPlayed=1, points=0, goalsScored=0, goalsConceded=1, tablePosition=8}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Crystal Palace', numberWin=0, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=1, matchesPlayed=1, points=0, goalsScored=0, goalsConceded=3, tablePosition=9}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Brighton', numberWin=0, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=1, matchesPlayed=1, points=0, goalsScored=0, goalsConceded=2, tablePosition=10}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Chelsea', numberWin=0, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=2, matchesPlayed=2, points=0, goalsScored=2, goalsConceded=5, tablePosition=11}
TeamStatistic{teamName='Leicester', numberWin=0, numberDraw=0, numberLoss=2, matchesPlayed=2, points=0, goalsScored=4, goalsConceded=6, tablePosition=12}
```

Comment: Arsenal is at `tablePosition=0`? That is not possible in the Premier League ;-)

Comment: @deHaar no man. I copy and past the wrong output. I edit the post

Comment: No problem... Was just wondering about this table position ;-)

Comment: @gccodec wow, thank you so much, this is an incredible amount of help! I'll give it a go now

Comment: @gccodec I get an error in the FootballMatchCSV reader  line 4, it says 'The method toList() is undefined for the type FootballMatchCSVReader'

Comment: Yes @LewysB.  You Need to static import the connector function of toList. I Will edit the post with All import

Comment: @gccodec solved that issue now only get 2 errors left that i believe to have the same problem 'The method reducing(BinaryOperator<TeamStatistic>) is undefined for the type' and  'The method comparingInt(TeamStatistic::getPoints) is undefined for the type FootballMatchStatisticsEngine' so I will await the imports :) thank you ever so much for all your help